# Change Custom List ID

Tags: 2010, custom-list, content-query-web-part, data-view-web-part

I am looking to query a custom list that exists in many sub sites. Using either the CQWP or a DVWP I'm running into the list limit. As the ID is 100, there a lots of custom lists (not just limited to the lists I'm interested in). If I set MaxListLimit to 0 I can query, but its very slow and probably using a lot of memory.

The list I'm using is based on a template. Can I set the list id myself, therefore querying a much smaller number of lists?

1. Can it be set in the template stp?
2. Can you change the list id for existing lists?